# Spring minimal REST404 get request

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I can't manage to get a simple REST service working. As far as I can tell by the numerous examples I've read, I only need to return a POJO while having the jackson dependencies fulfilled in order to get a json response in the client.

I'm using IntelliJ Idea (EE) as my IDE and tomcat7 as the web server. Tomcat logs register the deployment and the facets configuration within the IDE is identical to other non-rest working examples I've done. Tomcat access log gives me this error when calling the /index mapping from my browser:

`127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2017:13:10:45 +0100] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 404 949`

This is the code of the REST controller (it's logged as an error so I don't miss it):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class HomeController {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName());

  @Autowired
  MessageSource messageSource;


  @GetMapping(value = "/index")
  public TestObj greeting(){
  //public TestObj greeting(@RequestParam(value ="numbers", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int numbers){

    log.error("request logged");

    TestObj testObj = new TestObj();
    testObj.setLetters("letters");
    testObj.setNumber(0);

    return testObj;
  }

}
```

Servlet initializer:

```
package com.javalearning.simbus.config;


import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
  }

}
```

Application context configuration code (I've obviously already tried with the code uncommented, I still don't understand it fully though):

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.javalearning.simbus" )
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
  }
/*
  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
        = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
  }
*/
  @Bean
  public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
  }
}
```

Directory structure:

```
src/main/java/
└── com
    └── javalearning
        └── simbus
            ├── config
            │   ├── AppInitializer.java
            │   └── WebConfig.java
            ├── controller
            │   └── HomeController.java
            └── domain
                └── TestObj.java
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You ahve an Annotation on Controller class Level and method Level, so your utl must be `/index/index`

Comment: Damn, and that was it. I know it's dumb, but once I overlook something I overlook it for good.

Do you mind posting this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: I have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an annotation on controller class level and method level, so your url must be `/index/index`.